# Count groups based on criteria - R

Tags: r, datatable

Hi i have this dataset

```
dt <- data.table(ID = c(1,1,2,3,4,5,5,6,7, 8, 9,9, 10, 10, 11, 12, 13,14, 15),
                 diagnosis = c("A", "B", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "A", "B", "C", "A", "A", "A", "B", "C", "A", "A", "A"),
                 Date = c("2013-01-01","2013-01-01","2010-01-12", "2013-01-12", "2013-01-26", "2010-01-02", "2010-01-02", "2010-01-14", "2011-01-12", "2012-01-12", "2010-01-12", "2013-01-02","2013-01-02","2010-01-12", "2013-01-12", "2013-01-26", "2013-01-14", "2013-01-28", "2020-01-01"))
```

I need to make a table that counts every diagnosis (A; B; C) for the year 2013 (`only_2013`, patients who only had a diagnosis in 2013), the years 2010-2012 (`only_10_12`, patients who only had a diagnosis in this yearperiod), paitent who have diagnosis in both year groups (`both`), and patients who have none in the year 2013 and years 2010-2012 (`none`,in this example just one person). If a person have two diagnosis at the same date then it should follow this priority list: 1. if one of the diagnosis is A, then A should always be counted as their diagnosis
2. if they have B and C, then B should be counted as their diagnosis
the wished output should be a table like this, with the number of count as value.

```
group  only_2013  only_10_12  both none
A                                
B                     
C
```

Hope it makes sense....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you rank the diagnoses and only include them if made on unique dates, the key step is ordering by `diagnosis` within `ID` and marking those dates where `ID` is duplicated, so they can be dropped from the final count table.

```r
setorder(dt, ID, Date, diagnosis)
dt[, duplicate_diagnosis := duplicated(Date),
    by = .(ID)
]
```

After that it is simply a case of creating columns based on the rules you set out, and then summarising by these columns:

```r
dt[, year := year(Date)]

dt[, `:=`(
    only_2013 = all(unique(year) %in% 2013),
    only_10_12 = all(year %in% 2010:2012),
    both = 2013 %in% year & any(2010:2012 %in% year),
    none = identical(setdiff(2010:2013, unique(year)), 2010:2013)
),
by = ID
]

dt[(!duplicate_diagnosis), lapply(.SD, sum),
    .SDcols = c("only_2013", "only_10_12", "both", "none"),
    by = diagnosis
]


#    diagnosis only_2013 only_10_12  both  none
#        <ord>     <int>      <int> <int> <int>
# 1:         A         6          3     3     1
# 2:         B         1          1     1     0
# 3:         C         2          1     0     0
```

Note: I have taken advantage of the fact that the alphabetical order of your diagnoses is the same as the order in which you want to prioritise them. If this is not the case with your real data you can set the order by making them a factor and setting the levels, e.g.:

```r
dt[, diagnosis := factor(
    diagnosis,
    levels = c("A", "B", "C"),
    ordered = TRUE
)]
```

Comment: Hi I get this error, when running this: dt[, `:=`(
    only_2013 = unique(year) == 2013,
    only_10_12 = all(year %in% 2010:2012),
    both = 2013 %in% year & any(2010:2012 %in% year),
    none = identical(setdiff(2010:2013, unique(year)), 2010:2013)
),
by = ID
]

error: Error in `[.data.table` (x, , . `:=`(only_2013 = unique(year) == 2013,
    only_10_12 = all(year %in% :  Suplied 2 items to be assigned to group 34 of size 3 in column 'only-2013'

Comment: That seems to just be the code. What is the error?

Comment: error: Error in [.data.table (x, , . :=(only_2013 = unique(year) == 2013, only_10_12 = all(year %in% : Suplied 2 items to be assigned to group 34 of size 3 in column 'only-2013'. The RHS length must either be 1 or match ...

Comment: Do you get this error with the sample data you posted or your real data? It could be caused by `NA` values in the `year` column.

Comment: I use a much bigger dataset with 6000 observations, but i have no NA in the variable year.

Comment: Does the code work on the sample data you posted? It works for me so that should help isolate whether it's a package issue or something to do with your data.

Comment: It works with the sample data - but I dont know why it doesnt work with the real data ?

Comment: I think the issue was using `==`. In groups with n unique values for year it will return a vector of length n, which is fine if there are always n rows, as there are in the sample data, but not if some of the years are repeated. I have edited - on mobile so can't test but it should work now. Let me know if not.

Comment: It gives the same error. In my real data the years can be repeated I have 4816 persons who have the year 2013could that be a problem? - thanks for the help anyways

Comment: Sorry if changing to `only_2013 = all(unique(year) %in% 2013)` didn't help I don't think I can suggest anything further. Without being able to replicate the problem I am just guessing.

Comment: Thanks! I have a follow-up questions - if I want to count the patients from the "both" group who have had a diagnosis in year 2013 - how can I make a new variable that include those patients in the only_2013 group?